# SetContent in tiptap removes styles

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to put some html into a tiptap editor, as I want edit what I have saved earlier. But if I have some inline styles inside, tiptap deletes it.
Does anybody know what I can do with it?

```
this.editor.setContent('<p style="text-align: center">fffff</p>')
```

Comment: you should work with classes

Comment: It also removes the classes...

Answer (score 0):

If you have TextAlignExtension `@tiptap/extension-text-align`, the text-align will keep.

You can verify here https://wode.vercel.app/tiptap

[image]